# How to make ghidra display the real offset from rbp

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

How to make ghidra display the actual offset from rbp in assembly? For the same program, ghidra shows  `mov dword [rbp + local_c], edi`
I want to see the actual offset from rbp instead of `local_c`

In assembly, the actual instruction is:
`mov dword [rbp-0x04], edi`

so offset is `-0x04`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offsets are listed at the top of the function:

[image: Ghidra Local Variables offsets]

You can also hover over the local variable name for a few seconds to see a popup with the offset.

If you want to permanently disable the variable offset translation, uncheck `Markup Stack Variable References` under `Edit -> Tool Options -> Options -> Listing Fields -> Operands Fields`.